# How to apply C# keyboard mapping scheme in VB 2008 Express Ed.?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, customization

I´m used to developt in C#, but these days I´m using Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition, and I´d like to apply the C# keyboard mapping scheme in this environment. When I go to the options window, the only mapping scheme that I can list is 'default', that means, the VB keyboard mapping :(

I don´t want to change al my shorcuts one by one, I´ll like to download more keyboard schemes. Does anyone know something about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing the following

- Open up a version of Visual Studio with C#
- Switch to the C# Key bindings
- Export your settings to a file
- Import these settings from Visual Basic 2008 Express